# How to build a list of GMT time zone offsets in Django?

Tags: django, python-3.x, timezone

I want to allow users to choose a time zone, like in the screenshot [image]

I tried using pytz.all_timezones list, but it is very long and inconvenient  to scroll and use.

Any ideas how to implement similar list of timezones in Django? Thanks.

Comment: Not all timezones are GMT offset. As in some timezones use daylight saving time, others don't. Not all tz's switch at the same moment. A timezone is thus more than just a difference with GMT. It also contains the rules when the clock changes.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I know that. But it is more convenient for users to select from list of offsets, not from list of timezones. That's why I'm looking for a way to add such feature.

Comment: It won't be very convenient for someone in an offset not in the list, such as `+5:30` used in India.